# Unable to await Axios call multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

Can someone explain to me why I am unable to perform consecutive axios API calls this way? I figured that since each call was `await`ed, then both calls would simply be treated the same way.

When I run this code, I get the following error:
`TypeError: parsedEmp is not iterable at Object.listEmployees`

I do not receive the same error for the Axios call above it. Here's my code:

```
async function listEmployees() {
    const { data } = await axios.get('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/graffixnyc/febcdd2ca91ddc685c163158ee126b4f/raw/c9494f59261f655a24019d3b94dab4db9346da6e/work.json')
    const parsedData = data
    emp_data = []
    for(comp of parsedData) {
        emp_data.push([comp['company_name'],comp['employees']])
    }
    const { data2 } = await axios.get('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/graffixnyc/31e9ef8b7d7caa742f56dc5f5649a57f/raw/43356c676c2cdc81f81ca77b2b7f7c5105b53d7f/people.json')
    const parsedEmp = data2
    rosters = []
    for(entry of parsedEmp) {
        if(entry['id'] == e) {
            company.employees.push({ first_name: entry['first_name'], last_name: entry['last_name']})
        }
    }
    return rosters
}
```

Comment: @Phil Ah, I see. So, could I instead add something like `.then((result) =>...` as a callback to set a local variable equal to the result?

Comment: No, no need for that. See below 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) requires you to use the property names present in the source object, otherwise the resulting variables will be `undefined`. The [Axios response object](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema) does not have a `data2` property.

You would need something like this to access the `data` property

```js
const response2 = await axios.get('https://...')
const parsedEmp = response2.data
```

or you can use this format to name the assigned variable

```js
const { data: data2 } = await axios.get(...)
const parsedEmp = data2
```

or even this to save an extra line each time

```js
const { data: parsedData } = await axios.get(/* first URL */)

// ...

const { data: parsedEmp } = await axios.get(/* second URL */)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can have the code like below

```
async function listEmployees() {
const { data: parsedData } = await axios.get('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/graffixnyc/febcdd2ca91ddc685c163158ee126b4f/raw/c9494f59261f655a24019d3b94dab4db9346da6e/work.json');
const { data: parsedEmp } = await axios.get('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/graffixnyc/31e9ef8b7d7caa742f56dc5f5649a57f/raw/43356c676c2cdc81f81ca77b2b7f7c5105b53d7f/people.json');

// get the employee details
let emp_data = [];
_.map(parsedData, (data) => {
    emp_data.push(data.company_name, data.employees);
});

// get the roster data
let rosters = [];
_.map(parsedEmp, (data) => {
    roster.push({ first_name: data['first_name'], last_name: data['last_name']});
});
return rosters;
}
```